# How to find all file has 4 characters in their name

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to find all files that have 4 characters in their name I try this command

```
ls [0-9A-Za-z]{4}
```

and

```
ls *????
```

they don't work any help

Comment: Try `ls ????` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
ls [0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]
```

or simpler as proposed in the comments by @[Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r)

```
ls ????
```

**You can't mix *regex* notation with *glob* notation.**

If you want to use *regex*, you can give a try to [find](/questions/tagged/find) :

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex './\w{4}'
```

#### Note:

```
\w
```

is the same as

```
[0-9A-Za-z_]
```

in regex, and

`-typef` is for filtering files only.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

```
ls ????

or 

echo ????
```

If you want to omit directories it's another story.